# java Triangle Задача

Tags: java

Конструктор, имеющий в качестве параметров координаты трех вершин.
Убедитесь, что эти точки относятся к вершинам треугольника.
Проверьте, что созданный треугольник существует и не является вырожденным.
Если это не так, используйте throw new IllegalArgumentException(), чтобы вызвать ошибку.
double area() – возвращает площадь треугольника.
Point centroid() – возвращает центроид треугольника.
код:

```
class Triangle {
    Point a, b, c;
    double length1, length2, length3;

    public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        if (a == null || b == null || c == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (((length1 + length2) < length3) || ((length1 + length3) < length2) || ((length2 + length3) <
                length1)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    public Point centroid(){
        double xc= (((a.getX()+b.getX()+c.getX())/3));
        double yc= (((a.getY()+b.getY()+c.getY())/3));
        return new Point(xc, yc);
    }

    private double length3() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getX() - b.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getY() - b.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    private double length2() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - c.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - c.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    private double length1() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - b.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - b.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    public double area() {

        length1 = length1();
        length2 = length2();
        length3 = length3();
        double s = (length1 + length2 + length3) / 2;
        return Math.sqrt(s * (s - length1) * (s - length2) * (s - length3));
    }
}
```

Выдает вот такое : riangleTest.testConstructorDegenerative1:44 Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   TriangleTest.testConstructorDegenerative2:50 Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   TriangleTest.testConstructorDegenerative3:56 Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
[ERROR]   TriangleTest.testConstructorDegenerative4:62 Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: тест ожидает что будет выбрашенно исключение при поптыке создания вырожденного треугольника, в данном случаии IllegalArgumentException

Comment: при проверке в конструкторе длины сторон имеют значение по умолчанию 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Перепишите площадь через косое векторное произведение, длины сторон вообще не нужны

```
 public double area() {
        return Math.abs(0.5*((c.getX() - a.getX()) * (b.getY() - a.getY()) - 
                    (c.getY() - a.getY()) * (b.getX() - a.getX())));
    }
```

Для проверки, что треугольник не вырожден, достаточно проверить, что `area` не равно нулю.

Comment: Проверка этой площади на равенство нулю - тема тяжелая: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charto/bigfloat/master/doc/robustr.pdf . Это не к вашему ответу замечание, это ТС (или его преподаватель) не знает с чем связался.

Comment: Да, действительно забыл про знак. Со сравнением с нулём в любом случае придётся встретиться - хоть и с длинами. Непросто, да.

Answer (score 0):

Вычисление длин сторон треугольника, надо вычислить до проверки на вырожденность, в конструкторе. А ещё in if statement я добавил "=". Последний вид контруктора выглядит:

```
public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        if (a == null || b == null || c == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;

        length1 = length1();
        length2 = length2();
        length3 = length3();

        if (length1 + length2 <= length3 || length1 + length3 <= length2 || length2 + length3 <= length1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

И вы можете найти краткое объяснение про вырожденный треугольник, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037859/13081799).